# PyPI: ModuleNotFoundError after installing a package

Tags: python, pip, package, installation

I have made a package for PyPI and uploaded my package there. But when I tried to `pip install rsa-cipher` (My package) and run `rsa` on another PC, it gives following error:

```
Trackback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\...\python\python36-32\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
     "__main__", mod_spec
   File "c:\...\python\python36-32\runpy.py", line , in _run_code
     exec(code, run_globals)
   File "c:\...\python\python36-32\Scripts\rsa.exe\__main__.py", line , in <module>
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RSA'
```

The github repository  https://github.com/PizzaPat/RSA-Cipher

How can I resolve this error?

P.S. it works on my current PC I am using to make this package. Both Windows 10 and have python 3.6 installed

Comment: Your github repo link is borken.